# Overriding styles of Angular 4 components

Tags: angular

I am writing an Angular library that contains re-usable components. I want to deliver some default stylings for these that make sense out of the box, but I want it to be easy to override these default styles or to do fine grained customizations when using these library components in an app.

What is the best practice when doing this? For example, if I have defined a component template for a 'test' component like this and I decided most of the time the width will be set to 50% (simplistic example):

```
<div class="title">
   Test
</div>

.title {
  width: 50%;
}
```

In one particular consumer app, I want this title to display 100% of the particular container I'm using:

```
<div class="container">
  <test></test>
</div>
```

In my SCSS for this app component I would then try to do something like:

```
test {
  .title {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

However currently I am having issues with CSS scope and inheritance precedence, and on more complicated components with many nested elements it might get tricky and unmaintainable to express this way.

Does this even make sense doing this or am I breaking component encapsulation by knowing too much about the internals using CSS like this? If so, how do you handle layout and styling of sub-components like this when trying to fit them into a bigger application? Should it be done instead via data binding particular attributes or an options object?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would include the SCSS source with the library and have users include your library from their main SCSS file. You can define variable defaults which they can override and such. That way they have more control over the styles.

Comment: You can see  https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming-your-components.md as guidance I like the way material team does theming it would be also applicable for your case I think.

Answer (score 0):

Create parameterized directives for the part which you would want customizable. Every implementation can then pass its own set of values to the directive. It will be something like

```
<test [userprop]="value"></test>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override style with the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selector as follows,

```
:host ::ng-deep test {
  .title {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: `deep` and `ng-deep` are deprecated. There seems to be an issue with Angular and scoping styles ATM.